Typesense inconsistent results
I have a database of records, which are grouped under two categories:

book
movie

There is a total of 118 records indexed. Each record has a field type, which represents one of the above categories.
My schema looks as follow:
[
    [
        'name' => 'type',
        'type' => 'string',
        'facet' => true,
        'sort' => true,
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'id',
        'type' => 'string',
        'sort' => true,
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'name',
        'type' => 'string',
        'sort' => true,
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'author',
        'type' => 'string',
        'sort' => true,
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'description',
        'type' => 'string',
        'sort' => true,
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'created_at',
        'type' => 'int64',
        'sort' => true,
    ],
],

Performing a search with the wild card * the correct number of records is returned:

however when I start searching and type just a single letter such as s (all records have that letter included in one of the searchable fields) - the results don't add up:

You'll see from the image above that when searching by facet book or movie - both results do not add up to the non-faceted result of 92.
Infix
Now, I found out that to search for phrases / letters within the words I need to send the request with infix=true. I tried this, but according to documentation:

NOTE: Infix search is meant for searching on small fields like email addresses, phone numbers, identifiers etc where infix search is specifically useful. Therefore, infix search only uses the first word in the query for searching.

I've updated the schema by adding 'infix' => true to name, author and description fields and re-created collection and re-imported all documents.
This poses another issue where I would like the large body content to also be searchable.
Also, using infix (which got rid of the problem of the inconsistent number of results) the whole words started to be highlighted as well as single letters, even with one letter matching:

The payload for the above was:
[
    "query_by" => "name,author,description",
    "infix" => "always,always,always",
    "q" => "s",
    "highlight_fields" => "name,author,description",
    "facet_by" => "type",
    "page" => 1,
    "per_page" => 10,
]

and the request with the facet filter added:
[
    "query_by" => "name,author,description",
    "infix" => "always,always,always",
    "q" => "s",
    "highlight_fields" => "name,author,description",
    "facet_by" => "type",
    "filter_by" => "type:book",
    "page" => 1,
    "per_page" => 10,
]

Also the way the results are prioritised isn't quite right - if it's the number of times keyword is found within the 3 fields then that screenshot above should have them in a different order as second record has more s present than the first one and so on.
So my questions here are:

Why without the infix and by just filtering by a single facet the totals do not add up compared to the search without the facet?
If infix is the right way forward, how should I tackle search on the large content body fields if infix is only to be used with the small fields?
How to fix the order in which the results are appearing by the number of times the given keyword appears collectively in all search designated fields of the document?

Any help would be much appreciated.
